# Is it possible to drag sibling img to desktop from selecting div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, siblings

I'm using a lightbox plugin and I want users to be able to click and drag the img onto desktop.

The markup is similar to this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="out"> 
    <img class="select" src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/>
    <div class="click"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.img {position:relative;}
.click {background-color:blue;height:100px;width:100px;position:absolute;top:10px;}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y3erm/2/

So, when I try to click on the image, I am actually clicking the div, so I can't drag the image to the desktop. Is is possible with Javascript or jQuery to do something like this? Something like switching the `mouse-event:active` to different element with class "select", maybe?

This is the lightbox I am using http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

Comment: Your div layer is over the img, maybe you should try the reverse and your image has no class img, this is its tag.
Is this what you want ?
http://jsfiddle.net/y3erm/4/

Comment: the css is already coming from the lightbox, so I don't think I can alter it. That's why I think I need to use JS/JQ. But that is how it should behave.

Comment: this is the lightbox I am using http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/, try dragging the 'pop-up' image to the desktop

Comment: First, you can alter css, with overriding classes. Second, you don't need to do this. Third, on site you provided img wrapped into anchor, no overlay div used. Why do you even need div.click?

Comment: @Tommi div.click is what is actually 'clicked' when you 'click' on the element.

Comment: your img tag has no img class, so those css rules don't apply. you can make the div blue and image partially transparent to achieve the same "ghost blue" look while catching clicks on the IMG...

Comment: > div.click is what is actually 'clicked' when you 'click' on the element. // I see it, I asked why you need this div?

Comment: @Tommi because it acts as 'previous image / next image' div that covers the entire `img`. See examples in the lightbox site.

Comment: @dandavis thank you for the suggestion, but that is not what I'm trying to achieve. The transparency is just to show the image behind the covering div. I want to be able to click div and drag sibling `img` to desktop, I think JS/JQ might work, but I think switching elements while having a mouse state of active won't work.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see any sample on site, where additional `div.click` is used. And answering directly to your question, `pointer-events: none` enables click-through − [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events), but of course you can't set event handler on element in this case. Also for IE it supported only in 11+ version.

Comment: @Tommi working examples can be seen here: http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/  just click thumbnail and inspect the element.

changing `div.lb-nav` to `display:none` gives me the result I want, but this removes the prev/next gallery effect. That's why I'm thinking jQuery would be my best route.

Comment: I know this borderlines clickjacking, but the desired result would be: clicking (and holding) on element actually selects the sibling `img` of the 'clicked' div. this way the `img` would be selected and allowed to to be dragged to desktop

Comment: Got it now, but I don't believe this is possible. Browser don't provide you the way of "conditional" click-through even with `pointer-events: none`, you can only enable or disable it. Even with detection of long-click via JS you probably will not able to change event target in process of dispatching. Maybe someone knows some hacks.

Comment: @Tommi "Even with detection of long-click via JS you probably will not able to change event target in process of dispatching." That might be my solution? If I get no answers maybe I'll put a bounty on this. It might get interesting. Thanks.

Comment: Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/66Hr2/). Click on kitten on 1 sec and it changes color: click-through is enabled, but drag is not. Uncomment `display: none` and cover will be totally hidden after long click, but this will not help also. Good luck and please post an answer here if this behavior is posible at all.